# Is it possible to skip launchscreen.storyboard file when running a multiplatform SwiftUI app on macOS?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, multiplatform, launch-screen

I selected `Multiplatform` template when creating a `SwiftUI` app in **Xcode** (it's Xcode 14.0 beta, in case it matters). My purpose is to run the app on iOS. I selected `Multiplatform` template just because I thought it would be fun to see how it runs on `macOS`.

In WWDC 2020, **Apple** introduced an `Info.plist` based approach to implement launch screen for `SwiftUI` apps. Unfortunately that approach was broken in **Xcode** 13. My experiment shows it's still not working in **Xcode** 14.0 beta, so I work around the issue by using a `storyboard` file to implement launch screen.

However, since `storyboard` is based on `UIKit`, that means it doesn't work on `macOS`. That explains why **Xcode** reported the following error when I tried to run the app on `macOS`:

> iOS storyboard doesn't support device type 'mac'

So I wonder, given the fact that the `Info.plist` based approach is broken in **Xcode** 13 and 14, how does one implement launch screen in a multiplatform app? Is it possible to skip the `storyboard` file on `macOS`? I checked around in **Xcode** but didn't find a way.

An additional question: which is the common approach to write app on `macOS`, writing a multiplatform app as I described above or writing two separate apps, one for `iOS` and one for `macOS`? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found that this works for a multiplatform app:

1. Go to Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources
2. Click on the dropdown for the storyboard resources
3. Select iOS only

(Screenshot is from XCode 14 beta)

[image: Copy Bundle Resources]

Comment: Thanks. After I posted the question I gave up the idea of using the same code base for apps on multiple platform, because my (hypothetical) macOS app is supposed to have a very different UI design. I'll just trust you for your answer and accept it. BTW, if you don't mind, can macOS app have a launch screen? (I have no experience in macOS app yet and I never see a macOS app with launch screen).

Answer (score 2):

`Storyboards` are not based on `UIKit`, they are based on `Cocoa` which is also responsible for `UIKit` & `AppKit`.

The error you're receiving is because your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` is specific to `iOS`, & not because it's base on `UIKit`(it's not). Also you can have `storyboards` when building for **Mac**.

To solve the problem: Open `LaunchScreen.storyboard`, expand the right sidebar, click on the document icon & uncheck your `macOSTarget` under `Target Membership`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm not sure if you're right, because to create a `Storyboard` file in Xcode, one needs to choose if it's for iOS or macOS. Maybe you meant `UIKit` and `AppKit` are just different variations of `Cocoa`? But on the upper level, a `Storyboard` file can't work for both at the same time. In my case, I created a `LaunchScreen` file, which is available on iOS only. Your suggestion doesn't work for me because there is no macOS target under `Deployment Target` (I suppose that's what you meant by `Target Membership`, which I can't find in File Inspector in Xcode 14.0 beta).

Comment: Timmy's answer is correct *if* you're doing things the old way, where you have separate Targets in your Xcode project for each OS (iOS, macOS, tvOS, watchOS, visionOS, iPadOS). Nowadays, with SwiftUI, you can have a universal Target, targeting all the platforms/destinations with (mostly) just a checkbox on the Target->General screen in Xcode (under "Supported Destinations"). In that case, @acorscadden answer is correct. The idea is the same in both: remove the iOS-specific storyboard file in the Mac build.